# Successful boot, but no video output

Tags: xorg, 12.10, display

Ok, just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an ASUS Zenbook UX32A (integrated graphics).

On boot, screen goes black, and doesn't come back on.  However, the computer boots successfully and I hear the login sound.

I can then log in successfully. If I now connect an external monitor the HDMI port, that monitor comes on and displays the desktop as though in dual-screen mode.  If I go into the display settings, turn the internal monitor off, apply, then turn it back on, it starts working with proper dual-screening.  If I pull out the HDMI cable, it still reverts back to single screen mode, with the internal monitor still on.  I can suspend and resume, and it still works.  However if I reboot, it stops working again.

How can I make the configuration persist between boots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently a kernel update seems to have fixed this problem for me, but if you are still experiencing it, the best tip I found was to put the computer to sleep (e.g. using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and turn it back on, and your built-in display should then be working fine.

Basically I think there was a problem with the kernel on this particular video device that on boot would just send the video it to an external adapter, even if there wasn't anything connected to it (completely ignoring the built-in display).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently bought the Asus UX32A which came with Windows 8. I couldn't stand Window 8 so I swapped to Linux. I fixed the issue by using the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Once all the files have finished updating, turn off the system and unplug the external monitor. Turn it back on and the built in graphics should be working fine. My system has a fresh install of ubuntu 12.10 and it's working just fine.